# Normal baking, very weird results

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I'm trying to bake a high res *Normal map* into a low res one. The high res is a duplicate of the low res; I used *Multiresolution* modifier. I also sculpted my model, then applied the *Multres*modifier and all other modifiers for all objects. I'm using a cage mesh, which is again a duplicate of the low poly. I used <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to scale all faces on their normals, so they have the same poly count as the low res *Normal map*.

The thing is, this is not the first time I have ever baked normals, but I've never seen something like this (check the image). I've double checked everything: All objects have smooth shading, all faces in my low poly are selected, and the Texture node is active in low poly's material node editor. I'm sure there's a logical reason for this, I just can't find it.

[image: objects set up for normal map baking]

The second image is of the cage I'm using.

[image: cage mesh and incorrect normal map]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved, I started a new file, appended the High res, Low res and the cage objects, and it worked as it should be, I don't know why this happened though.

[image]